# Filtering on Cube in Excel - Does not work correctly

Tags: filter, ssas, cube

I have a cube.. the product as a dimension. The product dimension is made by using the product code as the key. As a display name I have used Product Name.

In the data, I have 2 product codes with the same name:

Code: 6
Name: Wine

Code: 2100
Name: Wine

The cube processes successfully, and the data in the cube looks good. When I filter the product name to 'Wine', it only comes back with the first in the list (Code 6) and does not bring back the other product.

Has anybody had similar issues?

Please see the 5 screenshots below to see an example:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoNuE.jpg)[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azxfq.jpg)[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOAng.jpg)[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9OE2.jpg)[Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2x0d.jpg)